# sprites are blurred on mobile

Tags: mobile, unity-game-engine, sprite, blur

I'm making a 2D game in Unity3D. I drawed all my sprites in Photoshop with 600 pixels/inches. I've set Filter mode to Point, max size to 4096 and format to truecolor in import settings in unity. And it looks good when I run it in unity on PC. But, sprites look blurred on all mobile devices (android). I've made "Override for android", set max size 4096 and format "true color". Anyway, it is blurred on mobile. What is my mistake? Here are screens:

Here is how it looks on PC.

[image]

Here is how it looks on mobile.

[image]

Comment: Would be useful if you share the screen grabs please

Comment: Just to clarify. Blurriness happen in unity editor or on the device itself?

Comment: Only on device. Yeah, I've made this screen in editor, but it is identical to a thing I see on a mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to guess without any screengrabs, Uncheck Generate Mip Maps?
If not Mipmaps try settings below. It does look like Filtering option set different than Point. Triple check everything again.

[image: Texture settings]

Comment: Check again, also added screengrab

Comment: Switching it to texture and setting texture type to advanced actually helped! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your "Texture Type" to "Sprite(2D and UI)" in the import settings. Also why have you set the texture size so high?

Comment: Tried, it did not help.

Comment: Please can you show a screenshot of your import settings?